# Multiple forms/pages in one hook_menu()

Tags: forms, routes

Within `hook_menu()`, I added multiple (form/page)s.

```
function mymodule_hook(){
  $form[...]=aray(...);
  // ...
  return $form;
}

function other_hook_form(){
  $form[...] = aray(...);
  // ...
 return $form;
}

function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['section/form1'] = array(
    'title' => 'form1',
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_form',
     'access arguments' => array('arg1 arg2'),
     'type' => MENU_CALLBACK, );

  $items['section/form2'] = array(
    'title' => 'form2',
    'page callback' => 'other_hook_form',
     'access arguments' => array('arg1 arg2'),
     'type' => MENU_CALLBACK, );

  return $items;
}
```

With the first Item I don't have a problem because it calls `mymodule_hook()`, but the second one renders the markup without `<form>` tag. So no submit/validation hooks are fired.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `drupal_get_form` as your page callback and pass the id of your form to that. This will ensure the form is processed by Drupal.

For reference, take a look at how the aggregator module declares its form callbacks in [aggregator_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21aggregator%21aggregator.module/function/aggregator_menu/6).

Example:

```
$items['myurl'] = array(
  'title' => 'Page title',
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('my_form_id'),
  'access arguments' => array('my_permission'),
);
```